# Delay in Trigger Update

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle10g, delay

I want to create an Update trigger which updates the values of column say status1 in database after column say status2 has been updated of the same table ?

But this(the updating) should happen after a delay of 3 minutes.

Please provide sample code

Comment: (1) Why would you want to do such a thing? (2) You're not going to be able to do such a thing from inside a trigger. You'll probably need some sort of dbms_scheduler job. What have you tried?

Comment: i don't know anything about dbms_scheduler 
but i want to do it as i am working on a project which needs changing of status when user places order earlier and another if the user has paid for it within 3 minutes else the order has to be deleted or status reverted to say null
i could just come up with update trigger but don't know how to delay it for 3 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

1. Create a PL/SQL procedure that scans your table for orders that have been placed but not paid for after 3 minutes. I assume you have timestamps or something in the table so you can tell when the order was placed.
2. Create a [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm) job that calls your procedure. Have the job run every 3 (or 2, or 1) minutes.
3. Now, all you have to do is insert into your table normally.